# Chessboard bitmap out of memory: How to make the board a single bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, chess

I am trying to make a chess game with C# and consistently run into the issue of "Out of memory" after moving a few pieces. I am a beginner with C#. My goal is to make a functioning game of chess where the pieces can only be moved into valid places(ie pawn can only go forward unless it can take a diagonal piece, etc.) I know the solution is to make the board a single bitmap instead of a new bitmap every time a piece is moved, but am unsure of how to resolve it.

I'm not sure of where to go next, but I know that I need to resolve the bitmap issue before moving on to anything else. I think the problem is the code in the class. I've changed the part in the () from where the image file was located to GetImageLocation

This code is under the form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Checkards
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Pieces> chessBoard = new List<Pieces>();

        int move_col = -1;
        int move_row = -1;

        Bitmap DBrown = new Bitmap("E:\\VS\\Checkards\\Images\\DarkBrownSquare.png");
        Bitmap LBrown = new Bitmap("E:\\VS\\Checkards\\Images\\LightBrownSquare.png");

        Pieces.Player current = Pieces.Player.User;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Drawboard();
        }

        private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Drawboard();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Drawboard();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Pieces p = new Pieces(i, 1, Pieces.PieceType.Pawn, Pieces.Player.Computer);
                p.x = i;
                chessBoard.Add(p);
            }
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(0, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Rook, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(1, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Knight, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(2, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Bishop, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(3, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Queen, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(4, 0, Pieces.PieceType.King, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(5, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Bishop, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(6, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Knight, Pieces.Player.Computer));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(7, 0, Pieces.PieceType.Rook, Pieces.Player.Computer));

            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Pieces p = new Pieces(i, 6, Pieces.PieceType.Pawn, Pieces.Player.User);
                p.x = i;
                chessBoard.Add(p);
            }

            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(0, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Rook, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(1, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Knight, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(2, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Bishop, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(3, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Queen, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(4, 7, Pieces.PieceType.King, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(5, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Bishop, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(6, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Knight, Pieces.Player.User));
            chessBoard.Add(new Pieces(7, 7, Pieces.PieceType.Rook, Pieces.Player.User));
        }

        public void Drawboard()
        {
            Bitmap pawn = new Bitmap("E:\\VS\\Checkards\\Images\\BlackPawn.png");

            Bitmap landscape = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(landscape);

            g.Clear(Color.Black);

            float width = panel1.Width / 8.0f;
            float height = panel1.Height / 8.0f;

            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (((i % 2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0)) || ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 1)))
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(LBrown, i * width, j * height, width, height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(DBrown, i * width, j * height, width, height);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < chessBoard.Count; i++)
            {
                g.DrawImage(chessBoard[i].GetBitmap(), chessBoard[i].x * width, chessBoard[i].y * height, width, height);
            }

            Graphics g2 = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            g2.DrawImage(landscape, 0, 0);
            landscape.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }
```

This code is under the class "Pieces"

```
        public Bitmap GetBitmap()
        {

            return new Bitmap(GetImageLocation());
        }
```

I would hope to be able to run the code without the memory running out.

Comment: 1 - When done with a GDI resource (or any IDisposable item) you need to Dispose of it. Using a `using` clause is the recommended way. OOT will hit you real fast if you leak Bitmaps 2 - For persistent results never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..